How to handle expired token while making external api call in nextjs?
Below is my signin function, whenthe signin is successfull i am setting cookie.
export const signIn = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const res = await axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/signin",
      data: payload,
    });
    console.log("--Signin response--", res.data);

    const cookieData = { token: res.data.token, user: res.data.data };
    // Serialize the cookie with necessary options
    const cookieOptions = {
      httpOnly: true,
      secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production",
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, // 1 week
      path: "/",
    };

    // Set the cookie using cookies module
    cookies().set("onlyjs_cookie", JSON.stringify(cookieData), cookieOptions);
    return res.data;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("--Signin error--", err.response.data.message);

    throw new Error(err.response.data.message);
  }
};

Whenever i make external api calls, i am sending the beare token with request then the backend will check for the verification of token and if expired throws 401 error,
Below is my apiRequest reusable function
"use server";
import axios from "axios";
import { cookies } from "next/headers";

const appAxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/",
  withCredentials: true,
});

export async function ApiRequest(endUrl, method = "get", config = {}) {
  let errorMsg = null;

  const defaultConfig = {
    url: endUrl,
    method: method,
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/",
  };

  const finalConfig = { ...defaultConfig, ...config };

  try {
    const cookie = cookies().get("onlyjs_cookie")?.value;

    if (cookie) {
      const parsedCookie = JSON.parse(cookie);
      if (parsedCookie?.token) {
        console.log("--Cookie token--", parsedCookie?.token);
        finalConfig.headers = {
          ...finalConfig.headers,
          authorization: `Bearer ${parsedCookie.token}`,
        };
      }
    }

    const response = await appAxiosInstance(finalConfig);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    if (error?.response) {
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        cookies().delete("onlyjs_cookie");
      }
    } else if (error?.request) {
      errorMsg = "Cannot connect to the server";
    } else {
      errorMsg = "Unexpected error occurred!";
    }

    throw new Error(errorMsg || "Something went wrong");
  }
}

I am calling apiRequest from serve action below
export const getAllTutorials = async () => {
  try {
    await ApiRequest("tutorials");
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log("--Tutorials error--", err);
  }
};

If the 401 error comes in apiRequest then i simply want to delete the cookie which i previously set during signin and also want to redirect the user to login.
How can i achieve that?

The error i am getting is
headers can only be set using server actions or api route handlers
I have tried both approaches but no luck.
Please help me.
